# CodeIgniter load lang-file in extended controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, codeigniter-2

I have extended my CI_Controller like this:

```
// base extend
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
      public $CI = array();

      public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
      }
      public function isUser(){
      // for example
      }
}

// admin extended
class MY_AdminController extends MY_Controller {

     public $admin = array();

     public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->CI->lang->load('admin');

        $this->admin['lang'] = $this->CI->lang->line('admin');

        $this->CI->load->vars($this->admin);

     }


     public function isAdmin(){
     //for example
     }
}

// extends for modules
class MY_AdminModuleController extends MY_AdminController {
     public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI->load->view('_header');
     }
     public function isAllowedModule(){
     // example
     }
     public function pseudoDestruct(){
        $this->CI->load->view('_footer');
     }
}
```

So it works fine. But I try to hook `post_controller`event and add my `MY_AdminModuleController->pseudoDestruct()`, so I enabled hooks in config.php and added next lines to hooks:

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
    'class' => 'MY_AdminModuleController',
    'function' => 'pseudoDestruct',
    'filename' => 'MY_Controller.php',
    'filepath' => 'core'
);
```

But I got a problem at loading lang-file in MY_AdminController's constructor. It returns `null` when called from hook (`true` when I use it normaly) and I have Notice about undefined index at frontend. No, I don't want to disable notices, I want to fix the problem. Also I have config loadings in MY_AdminController's constructor and them loading good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, not in that particular way at least. CodeIgniter is designed to only have one controller instance, while the hooks create new instances and your lang files are not loaded in that new instance.
Also, you don't need to call `get_instance()` from your controller class - the class IS what `get_instance()` returns.

Anyway, you can declare a regular function to use as a hook, there's no problem putting it in your MY_Controller.php file as well:

```
function pseudo_destruct()
{
    get_instance()->load->view('_footer');
}
```

Then use this hook:

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
    'function' => 'pseudo_destruct',
    'filename' => 'MY_Controller.php',
    'filepath' => 'core'
);
```

Comment: That works! Thank You for an answer, mate, You saved my time and, I hope, someone's who will google this question too.